# Retrieve value from sum function

Tags: django, python-3.x

```
sum_acquired_value = Investment.objects.filter(customer=pk).aggregate(Sum('acquired_value'))
```

The result is

```
{'acquired_value__sum': Decimal('125000')}
```

But I need the value `125000` to do calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of an [**`.aggregate(..)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset) is a simple dictionary:

> (..)
>
> `aggregate()` is a terminal clause for a `QuerySet` that, when invoked,
>   **returns a dictionary** of name-value pairs. The name is an identifier
>   for the aggregate value; the value is the computed aggregate. (..)

You obtain the value by performing a lookup, like:

```
the_sum = sum_acquired_value['acquired_value__sum']  # Decimal('125000')
```

You can then peform arithmetic with `the_sum` (note that a `Decimal` does not allow arithmetic with all types of numbers). In a template, the `str(..)` will be applied implicitly, rendering the value the `Decimal` class wraps.

The rationale is that you can perform multiple aggregates in the same query (for example the sum, average, minimum, and maximum all in the same query), and then you retrieve a dictionary that contains the values.

It might however be better to give the aggregate a name yourself:

```
the_sum = Investment.objects.filter(
    customer=pk
).aggregate(acquired_sum=Sum('acquired_value'))['acquired_sum']
```

Comment: This worked, how do I get the output as 125000.00 instead of just 125000?

Comment: @HemachandraGhanta: well the question is if that is a good idea, since a `Decimal` ensures decimally correct computations. But you can cast it to an `int`, or `float` with `int(the_sum)` and `float(the_sum)`. But this can result in rounding errors due to IEEE 754.